# Get current travel times for a list of destinations from Google Maps into a Sheet

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-maps-api-3, gis

I have a list of coordinates in Google Sheets (around 20). I'd like to input a location and receive current travel times to each coordinate, for the different transport modes.

Is this possible from Google Sheets? How, approximately, would I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Maps API. Here is a good [example from the documentation for getting travel time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder#getdirections).

You can wrap that example up in a function in the Script Editor and call it as a formula from your spreadsheet.

```js
// locations can be addresses or coordinates
// allowed modes are DRIVING, WALKING, BICYCLING, TRANSIT
function GETDISTANCE(location1, location2, mode) {
   var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
     .setOrigin(location1)
     .setDestination(location2)
     .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode[mode])
     .getDirections();
   return directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
}

// directions from Times Sq to Central Park, NY
Logger.log(getDistance("40.7591017,-73.984488","40.7670973,-73.9793693","WALKING") )
// -> "14 mins"
```

[image: Screenshot using custom GetDistance function in Google Sheets]